# need link to documentation on how to 'MASK' website content while creating a TYPO3 template as a extension

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I am trying to create a template which can be reused in TYPO3. I want to offer it as a free extension for the community. Currently I am following the standards specified in youtube video series https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HtBmim7pc0o and https://www.sitepackagebuilder.com/ ) and  https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package.
I need to 'MASK' the template but cannot get access to relevant Tutorials. Can anybody help me out?
Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: please be more specific what you want. and be aware: there is an extension `mask` for defining contentelements, which might confuses readers of your question (try to avoid the word and tag "mask")

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: Please make your question more clear for future readers. The tags are explicitly defined in the tag wiki, e.g. mask: "An image mask is a bitmap that specifies an area to paint, ..." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mask

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap_package/Configuration/TypoScript/constants.typoscript you see:

```
page.fluidtemplate {
            # cat=bootstrap package: advanced/100/100; type=string; label=Layout Root Path: Path to layouts
            layoutRootPath = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/
            # cat=bootstrap package: advanced/100/110; type=string; label=Partial Root Path: Path to partials
            partialRootPath = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/
            # cat=bootstrap package: advanced/100/120; type=string; label=Template Root Path: Path to templates
            templateRootPath = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/
        }
```

Or:

```
###############
### FELOGIN ###
###############
styles.content.loginform {
    templateFile = EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Templates/FrontendLogin/FrontendLogin.html
}
```

This part tells the templates are loaded from those paths. To override (you say mask i believe) place a copy (which you are going to edit) inside a folder and put in your constants file:

```
page.fluidtemplate {
            layoutRootPath = fileadmin/folder/folder/Layouts
            partialRootPath = fileadmin/folder/folder/Partials
            templateRootPath = fileadmin/folder/folder/Templates
}
```

Or:

```
styles.content.loginform {
    templateFile = fileadmin/folder/folder/yourcopyofthefile.html
}
```

So you can override single templates and entire template folders. Copy the files from an extensions "Resources/Templates" or "Resources/Partials" etc.

Constants can be edited with a constants file set in the backend at Your Root Template (default root template) > Edit > General > Constants field and use :

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/folder/folder/typoscript/constants.ts">
```

Or directly in that field use the code for your override.

Hopefully it helps you further.

Comment: You are welcome Sharmistha :) Could you give me a vote if answer is ok for you? If you need more help let me know.

Comment: It's also possible to use `layoutRootPaths`, `partialRootPaths` and `templateRootPaths` which you can use to selectively override some files instead of coping the whole base template, see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html#templaterootpaths for reference.

Comment: Hi Rusty I have voted your answer. If you still don't see it, let me know. I have followed your instruction and completed the template. The acid test will be when the TYPO3 community accepts my work. Thanks again.

Comment: nice to hear that:)

Comment: Hi Rusty  Good morning. Tried Masking the way you mentioned but facing some problems. Cant post the entire details on Stackexchange. Any other forum or email where I can directly share the coding issues I am facing?

Comment: think I need 100 reputation to chat:( have only 70 now